# after and before pseudo elements attr(title) with break line

Tags: html

\n,\r, 
, 
 it didn't work for them.
How to go to a bottom line?

```css
.question:hover::before {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="question" title="first line
second line
third line">?</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add white-space:break-spaces;

```css
.question:hover::before {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    white-space:break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<p class="question" title="first line
second line
third line">?</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre>` instead of `<p>`.
`<pre>` is preformated text; wich means it shows spaces and newline instead of `<p>` which just removes them.

```css
.question:hover::before {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<pre class="question" title="first line 
second line 
third line">?</pre>
```

Comment: overflows from specified width when text is too long